# Magento2 installation problem

Tags: magento2, php, installation, localhost

I try to install Magento2 in My local system but I got **PHP Extension intl error**

[image]

Comment: I propose to use vagrant to install Magento2. For example https://github.com/rgranadino/mage2_vagrant.

Comment: You should enable the missing libraries required for Magento installation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open php.ini file and find the line ;extension=php_intl.dll and remove semicolon (;) and save the file and then restart your xamp or wamp server and refresh the installation page.this error will be gone.

Note:- for more information on the above error see http://pradeepsanku.com/2015/11/20/php-intl-extension-is-missing-during-installation-of-magento-2-magento-2/

**PHP Extension intl is missing**

```
;extension=php_intl.dll
```

Un comment the line from both php.ini

```
1.  \wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin
2.  \wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12
```

And search for .dll files in **\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12**  start with **icu** i.e. **icuxxx.dll** copy all these files(around 8 files) and paste/replace in  **\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin**

Restart the wamp & recheck readiness check.

Comment: I've uncomment the line but still getting extension is missing. My PHP version is 5.5.12

Comment: after uncomment you have to restart your apahe server.have you did this ?

Comment: yes. but not working. Check @Neeraj Garg answer point no 3 is work for me.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, Magento 2 was released today.

You're missing a PHP extension. I don't know your setup, but on Ubuntu with Apache you can install the missing extension with:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-intl
```

After that you should reload apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: actually i tried to instal in my local system How i check this

Comment: You can check this post that contains the same missing extension as you do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285280/cakephp-3-0-installation-intl-extension-missing-from-system. But as KAndy pointed out, you could beter use Vagrant for Magento2 development.

Answer (score 2):

For windows:-

**1. xampp version**

assuming you are using latest version of xampp. can be download from here:-

https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

**2. php.ini**

If you are using Xampp on local you can find the php.ini at /xampp/php/php.ini

In this file search for

**;extension=php_intl.dll**

and changed this to

**extension=php_intl.dll**  (remove semicolon from front)

**3. .dll files**

go to **xampp/php** and search for .dll files start with **icu** i.e. **icuxxx.dll**

copy all these files(around 8 files) and paste/replace in **xampp/apache/bin**

Now try again with installation. This should work.

Comment: also if images not showing in back-end and front-end then you can follow these steps http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/92485/4342

Answer (score 1):

**I had the same problem a few days ago.**
**Setp 1:-**
You have to copy all the files (all files starts with **icu***):
**From:** /bin/php/php5.4.3/

icudt.dll
icudt46.dll
icuin.dll
icuin46.dll
icuio.dll
icuio46.dll
icule.dll
icule46.dll
iculx.dll
iculx46.dll
icutest.dll
icutest46.dll
icutu.dll
icutu46.dll
icuuc.dll
icuuc46.dll

**Setp 2:-**  Copy here
**To:** = /bin/apache/apache2.2.22/bin/

**Setp 3:-** And you also need to **enable intl in php.ini** file (uncomment this line):

;extension=php_intl.dll

=> And restart the server. It should works fine. :)

Answer (score 1):

For removing **PHP Extension intl** error, we have to enable `PHP Extension intl` , follow the Steps..

```
Open the xampp/php/php.ini file in any editor.
Search ";extension=php_intl.dll"

kindly remove the starting semicolon ( ; )

Like :

;extension=php_intl.dll

to

extension=php_intl.dll

Save the xampp/php/php.ini file.
Restart your xampp/wamp
```

Hope its work..Cheers..

Answer (score 0):

Installing Wamp 2.5 on windows 8 if you do not need to change the default **port 80**
go to **control panel->administrative tools->services** search for world wide web 
publishing service which is the second last usually and click on stop and set to disable for permanent basis.restart your Wamp and its done.

Answer 3 solved my problem I am using Wamp version 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the `php.ini` at `/xampp/php/php.ini`

search for

`;extension=php_intl.dll`

and change this to

`extension=php_intl.dll` (remove semicolon from front)

after save the file, you need to re-start your Xampp.