# Magento2 does not showing images/css/js

Tags: magento2, javascript, css, installation, static-content

I have installed Magento 2 but for some reason all the css/js/images are not loaded.
Below are the steps I follow to install Magento 2

- Create a sub-domain on cpanel
- Downloaded Magento and uploaded via FTP to the sub-domain
- Via cPanel FileManager extracted the `tar.gz` file
- Follow the setup wizard (we have MySQL 5.6 and PHP 5.5 - the setup went fine without any problems)

Do I need extra software on my server (like composer)?

I have searched for a solution into this but so far no luck

- I've tried to change `di.xml` file but no luck
- I've tried to run the `static-content:deploy` but I get errors

Comment: Backend is working whick means all links

Comment: the backend also has issues with the css/js/images

Comment: Links are working

Comment: some links work some dont

Comment: ok try my answer

Answer (score 5):

Try to use this command in the terminal:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

If you are using the Magento 2.1.* on **default** or **development** mode try this:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this. Before trying make sure to make a **backup**

Remove everything, except `.htaccess` file from `pub/static folder`

Open up `app/etc/di.xml` find the path `“Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink”` and replace to `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`

Note: Remove entire files and folder under `pub/static` except `.htaccess` file.

For More info ref this http://www.dckap.com/blog/magento-2-admin-links-not-working-in-windows/

Comment: i've already tried this with no luck. I'm using a CentOS, Apache 2.2.31

Comment: Try to clear cache session and then check

Comment: still no luck, but a strange thing is sometimes some image/css/js loads but not completely...the link is http://formacao.primariu.com/what-is-new.html

Comment: You are upgrade this?

Comment: no, its a fresh installation with the sample data, to see whats new about Magento2

Comment: did you change file permission

Comment: what do you mean about file permission? (its the default after extract/install)

Comment: take backup and set 777 for all

Comment: if i set to 777 i get an Internal Server Error... the missing files now are some css and js (requireJS included)...on a pub/static/...../en_US/....

Comment: our server dont have composer installed, can be it the cause of the isseu?

Comment: Please Check Apache Rewrite is enable or not.if not enable please enable and check.

Answer (score 3):

If you are in default or development mode use -f to forcefully download static content. In development mode static content are downloaded automatically.

```
  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

In Production mode,no deed to forcefully depoy.

```
  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 1):

Check these extensions:

PHP Extension curl.
PHP Extension dom.
PHP Extension mcrypt.
PHP Extension simplexml.
PHP Extension spl.
PHP Extension xsl.
PHP Extension intl.
PHP Extension mbstring.
PHP Extension ctype.
PHP Extension hash.
PHP Extension openssl.
PHP Extension zip.
PHP Extension xmlwriter.
PHP Extension gd.
PHP Extension iconv.

Check file permissions:

`"{"path":"directorypath/htdocs/magento2/app/etc"}"` writable directory permission.
`"{"path":"directorypath/htdocs/magento2/var"}"` writable directory permission.
`"{"path":"directorypath/htdocs/magento2/pub/media"}"` writable directory permission.
`"{"path":"directorypath/htdocs/magento2/pub/static"}"` writable directory permission.

Answer (score 1):

You can see my concise and complete answer to the same problem here:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/97230/34408

However, I have written an excellent article about it and gathered each and every possible solution to it.

[How To Fix Broken Magento 2 Installation](http://magenticians.com/fix-broken-magento-2-installation)

**I hope this will solve your problem as it has already been working for so many people.**